# Visual Studio 2012 and Intellisense

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

I think this is just happening to me, but every time I start my project in VS I have to do devenv.exe/resettsettings otherwise the intellisense doesn't work. Does anyone know any special reasons as to why?

Comment: Does it show up when you use `Ctrl + Space` ?

Comment: You should try removing all installed extensions, one may be messing up with the settings.

Comment: @V4Vendetta no it doesn't really strange.Kookiz this is a new fresh install on my machine.

Comment: Did you try re-installing visual studio?

Comment: Not sure whether it's related, but I occasionally find it stops working whilst working on a file. Closing and reopening the file brings it back though. Not isolated what triggers it disappearing yet though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These options should be enabled:

```
Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->General->Auto list members
Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->General->Parameter information
Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Intellisense->Show completion list after a character is typed
```

If it doesn't work try this:
`Tools->Import and export settings->Reset all settings`

Comment: Resetting all settings is working for him. He's having to do it everytime he starts Visual Studio.

Comment: I have same symptoms and these settings are same. any more clues what cause this behaviour? thanks

Comment: I have all this settings but anyways VS 2012 doesnt work properly at all. I.e. when I start to input `myMediaElement.` and it it shows some errors but no the its methods.

Answer (score 3):

after many posts, I can solve this problem well:

Execute developer prompt command for visual studio 2012 --> `gacutil /u Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language.Interop`

solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

Close the current Tab (in which Intellisense is not working) and reoppen it. Many times this was enough for me, boring, but enough.