# VS2012 Intellisense broken for Workflow projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, workflow, intellisense

I am currently working on a Workflow dll in VS2012 c#. At some point my intellisense in that projected decided to stop working. It does not auto come up but it opens when I use the keyboard shortcut. NOW even when it opens with the keyboard shortcut it doesn't work. By that I mean it doesn't pick up anything thing I added aka. my references to other DLLs, folders in the solution containing workflow.xamls, usings etc.

I decided to test it in a new clean project, it worked for a bit then suddenly 3 workflows in it just did the same thing. Doesn't pick up the workflow or any of my added classes.

Screen shots;
[image]
[image]

I have tried a lot of different possible fixes:

- [Deleting sln file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561074/syntax-intellisense-broken)
- Refreshing cache (crtl shift r  if i recall correctly)
- Deleting %AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ReflectedSchemas
- Resetting settings to default
- Checking if its enabled (intellisense)
- Restart VS
- Restart laptop

Any ideas? I really need some help on this.

**EDIT**
Tested the project on another pc and it does the same. Problem seems to be with the solution/project.

Comment: Got any addins running?

Comment: There are some solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992983/intellisense-and-code-suggestion-not-working-in-vs2012-ultimate-rc?rq=1

Comment: @MatthewWatson No addons/ins running.

Comment: @Andy I already tried those fixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at this again and debugging what was wrong further (clean projects, adding in dll's one at a time etc) I discovered that adding the Microsoft.Net.Http dll to a WorkFlow project broke the intellisense.

[Microsoft report on it.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809676/microsoft-net-http-in-a-workflow-project-destroys-intellisense)

**EDIT:**

> > The reason is System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll references System.Runtime.dll and System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll, but these 2
> >     dlls were not referenced in the project.
>
> Removing System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll from references or add
>   references to references System.Runtime.dll and
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll would bring back IntelliSense.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, I resolved this by adding the following references to my project (Windows Workflow Foundation 4.5 on .NET 4.5):

- System.Runtime.dll (from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Runtime.dll)
- System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll (from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll)
- System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll (from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll)

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+ALT+SPACE toggles Intelisense between suggestion and completion mode ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that's not the problem. It is not working. It doesn't pick up classes/dlls etc that I have added. Or even folders for that matter.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, i just didnt get the question right... but maybe this will help you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210593/visual-studio-2012-and-intellisense)

Answer (score 1):

We have had the exact problem-only with the new Prism dlls. Shauns answer helped us find the fix. So if someone encounters the problem and finds the following dlls in his project - he could attempt removing them:

- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.Desktop.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.SharedInterfaces.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll

These are OK and can be left in the solution:

- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition.dll
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.PubSubEvents.dll